# Python tkinter window call causes system restart

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I'm new to using `tkinter` and really yet to start since calling it is causing my computer to restart.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter

a = tkinter.Tk()

a.mainloop()
```

I'm only attempting to view the window. But when I call this, i see the file open and then my computer restarts.

I'm attempting to view the window using `macOS` `Mojave version: 10.14.6`

Here's an image of the Terminal on restart:

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0maN.png)

Comment: I'd be surprised if that code is not giving you a syntax error actually. But aside of the typo, it should work fine.

Comment: My mistake, what I've loaded here has "Import" with a cap "I". I've written it as a lowercase "i" in my script. - I've made the change to the question.

Comment: Have you tried running it line by line and see what triggers the restart? Have you checked your OS logs?

Comment: Yep tried that the restart is triggered on "a = tkinter.Tk()" The logs are above.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating python, tkinter and maybe your OS. I am running tkinter on mac too and it works fine.